# how to check if a string is empty or null in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

In my project I have an `edit text` field and its name is `editText` also I have assign `mTextEmri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);` I want to get its value and I have done it with the following statment `String emridhene = mTextEmri.getText().toString();`

Now I want to check it if it is `null` or `empty` I have tried this code but it is not working

```
if (emridhene.toString() == null || emridhene.toString() == "") {
                mTextViewKonfirm.setText("Ju lutem shkruani nje Emer");
            }
           else{
                mTextViewKonfirm.setText(emridhene);
            }
```

How can I make it to work. Thanks.

Comment: if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString))

Comment: did you google for "java compare strings" ?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just Use

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(/* your String*/)){
  // String is empty or null
}else {
  // string has value
}
```